# Compare values with a partial match then store matched data into new variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am trying to compare a specific column value based on an active cell selection to a group of data in another sheet. This only has to be a partial match.

Example: comparing data value one in sheet one (1234) to a bunch of rows in column 1 of sheet 2 (1235TN, 1234TN etc) Basically I am looking for a partial match of the first 4 characters. Once found store the matched data in sheet 2 to a new variable.

I hope that is clear enough? Here is my sample code. all of the data gets pulled from both sheets, I just don't know how to partial match them and store the correct value.

```
function compare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var col = 1;
  var value = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();
  var lookupSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test');
  var value2 = lookupSheet.getRange('A1:A150').getValues();
}
```

In the code above I am comparing value to value2, if value partially matches value2(4 characters) then store value2

Best,

D
[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlkog.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Find partial matches

```
function compare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');//You can change to active sheet
  var row = sh.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var col = 1;
  var n = sh.getRange(row, col).getValue();
  let re = new RegExp(`^${n.slice(0,4)}`,'');//first four characters
  let o = [];
  var lookupSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');//you can change sheet name
  lookupSheet.getRange('A1:A150').getValues().flat().forEach((e,i) => {
    
    if(e.toString().match(re)) {
      o.push({value:e,row:i+1});
    }
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

Comment: After updating with my sheet info I am getting the result of [ ] which is for o. Is there supposed to be something in the brackets for o? Its like the match is not being pushed to o? Also is this a partial match for the first 4 characters of the search? Sorry this type of programming is a little new to me.

Comment: Please provide a table of you comparison data so that we can check our code with real data.  I have performed a basic functionality test but it may not be reflecting the complexity found in your data.  To be the most useful for us your data should be provide in a form that makes it easy for us to copy and paste into our spreadsheet.  SO tables are very good ways to accomplish that.

Comment: I added a link to the original post. The column on the left highlighted in green is the data acting as value 1 and are searching for, but only the first 4 characters. The column on the right highlighted in red is the column we are searching in for the partial match. When the partial match is found the data in the red column is stored. I hope that helps?

Comment: Actually I just added a modification to extract only the first four characters so that should do the job for you.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I am still getting this as a result of the logger: 1:28:04 PM Info [ ] does not seem to be passing the info? Thank you so much for your help on this.

Comment: I just tested it and it seems to be working for me.  Did you get the code with the slice in the template literal

Comment: Is there a way to pass the found logged value into a variable that can be used in other areas? Currently if I use "o" my output is object object. Thanks again

Comment: If there is only one then it would `be o[0].value`

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare() {
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const value = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 1)
                     .getDisplayValue()
                     .slice(0, 4)

  const partialMatch = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                     .getSheetByName(`Sheet1`)
                                     .getRange(`A1:A150`)
                                     .getDisplayValues()
                                     .flat()
                                     .find(cell => new RegExp(`${value}`, `i`).test(cell))

  if (partialMatch) Logger.log(partialMatch)

}
```